# Storing and retrieving raw XML in Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I need to store and retrieve raw SOAP XML in Oracle. What is the simplest way to do that? Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as a straightforward VARCHAR2 column or use the data type of XMLType. This will make it easier to query using XQuery directly if that is something you envisage.

This is Oracle's XML developer guide - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_xquery.htm#CBAGCBGJ